# Setting a variable within a bash PS1

Tags: bash, ps1

I'm trying to customize my bash prompt and I'm having trouble with a few conditionals.

My current `PS1` looks like this.

```
export PS1="\
$PS1USERCOLOR\u\
$COLOR_WHITE@\
$COLOR_GREEN\h\
$COLOR_WHITE:\
$COLOR_YELLOW\W\
\`if type parse_git_branch > /dev/null 2>&1; then parse_git_branch; fi\`\
\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo -e '$COLOR_WHITE'; else echo -e '$COLOR_RED'; fi\`\$\     
$COLOR_WHITE"
```

- The first 6 lines just set regular `PS1` stuff.
- Line 7 then calls a function to display the current git branch and status if applicable.
- Line 8 then tests the return code of the previous command and changes the colour of the `$` on the end.
- Line 9 sets the prompt back to white ready for the user's command.

However line 8 is responding to the return code from line 7's function and not the previous command as I first expected.

I've tried moving line 8 before line 7 and eveything works as it should. But I don't want line 8 before line 7, the `$` must be on the end.

I've tried setting a variable earlier on to be the value of `$?` and then testing that variable like so

```
export PS1="\
\`RETURN=\$?\`\
$PS1USERCOLOR\u\
$COLOR_WHITE@\
$COLOR_GREEN\h\
$COLOR_WHITE:\
$COLOR_YELLOW\W\
\`if type parse_git_branch > /dev/null 2>&1; then parse_git_branch; fi\`\
\`if [ \$RETURN = 0 ]; then echo -e '$COLOR_WHITE'; else echo -e '$COLOR_RED'; fi\`\$\     
$COLOR_WHITE"
```

But this doesn't work.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: I'd split all the if statements into a separate function or script, and test independently.  return the color as as string

Comment: You are setting a variable in a sub-shell. That doesn't carry to another sub-shell or the parent shell.

Comment: That makes sense! Any idea how to do this correctly?

Comment: Don't use two sub-shells for the two tests. Use one, set `RETURN` at beginning of that sub-shell and then use it the end.

Comment: See also [How to get green/red terminals under OpenBSD?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38050/how-to-get-green-red-terminals-under-openbsd) and [Stateful bash function](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124902/stateful-bash-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way is to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` like so:

```
prompt_cmd () {
    LAST_STATUS=$?
    PS1="$PS1USERCOLOR\u"
    PS1+="$COLOR_WHITE@"
    PS1+="$COLOR_GREEN\h"
    PS1+="$COLOR_WHITE:"
    PS1+="$COLOR_YELLOW\W"
    if type parse_git_branch > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        PS1+=$(parse_git_branch)
    fi
    if [[ $LAST_STATUS = 0 ]]; then
        PS1+="$COLOR_WHITE"
    else
        PS1+="$COLOR_RED"
    fi
    PS1+='\$'
    PS1+="$COLOR_WHITE"
}
```

Since `PROMPT_COMMAND` is evaluated prior to each prompt, you simply execute code that sets `PS1` they way you like for each prompt instance, rather than trying to embed deferred logic in the string itself.

A couple of notes:

1. You must save `$?` in the first line of the code, before the value you want is overwritten.
2. I use double quotes for most of the steps, except for `\$`; you could use `PS1+="\\\$"` if you like.

Comment: That's excellent and far more elegant. I've used it exactly like that, although I've added a space after the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution to this problem is to make use of the `bash` environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  If you set this variable to the name of a shell function, said function will be executed before each `bash` prompt is shown.  Then, inside said function, you can set up whatever variables you want.  Here's how I do almost exactly what you're looking for in my `.bashrc`:

```
titlebar_str='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]'
time_str='\[\e[0;36m\]\t'
host_str='\[\e[1;32m\]\h'
cwd_str='\[\e[0;33m\]$MYDIR'
git_str='\[\e[1;37m\]`/usr/bin/git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | /bin/grep -m 1 ^\* | /bin/sed -e "s/\* \(.*\)/ [\1]/"`\[\e[0m\]'
dolr_str='\[\e[0;`[ $lastStatus -eq 0 ] && echo 32 || echo 31`m\]\$ \[\e[0m\]'
export PS1="$titlebar_str$time_str $host_str $cwd_str$git_str$dolr_str"

function prompt_func {
    # Capture the exit status currently in existence so we don't overwrite it with
    # any operations performed here.
    lastStatus=$?

    # ... run some other commands (which will have their own return codes) to set MYDIR
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_func
```

Now bash will run `prompt_func` before displaying each new prompt.  The exit status of the preceding command is captured in `lastStatus`.  Because `git_str`, `dolr_str`, etc. are defined with single quotes, the variables (including `lastStatus`) and commands inside them are then re-evaluated when bash dereferences `PS1`.

Comment: Using `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you would typically just conditionally set the value of, e.g, `dolr_str` inside the function, rather than try to embed a command in the value of `dolr_str`.

Comment: True.  The above is the result of many edits done in many differing states of mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I need to use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable to set the `RETURN` variable. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a command which is called before `PS1` is loaded.

My script now looks like

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='RETURN=$?'

export PS1="\
$PS1USERCOLOR\u\
$COLOR_WHITE@\
$COLOR_GREEN\h\
$COLOR_WHITE:\
$COLOR_YELLOW\W\
\`if type parse_git_branch > /dev/null 2>&1; then parse_git_branch; fi\`\
\`if [[ \$RETURN = 0 ]]; then echo -e '$COLOR_WHITE'; else echo -e '$COLOR_RED'; fi\`\$\     
$COLOR_WHITE"
```

Comment: You might as well do the full if test in `PROMPT_COMMAND` and set a variable with the string to use in `PS1`.